# Negation of regular expression pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression pattern: `[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}`.

Is there some way to negate this pattern? I mean that using that expression I should be able to match all substrings that *do not match* this pattern.

I tried a negative look behind - `(?!(a-zA-Z0-9{8}))`, but that has never worked in JavaScript.

Comment: You can use it in a `.split()`. Check https://jsfiddle.net/hwpaqmn9/

Comment: Do you want to match a string, or do you want to test a string?

Comment: Yes, that works fine. I will try it in our company framework. I must implement that JSON there, but it may work. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, so I can post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to obtain all the substrings that do not match a specific pattern, you can use `String#split`:

```js
var re = /[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}/;
var s = "09 ,Septemeber";
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(s.split(re).filter(Boolean));
```

The idea is that those substrings that match will be delimiters, and will be missing from the obtained array.

I added `.filter(Boolean)` to get rid of empty array elements that often appear when splitting with a regex.

Note that the pattern should not contain capturing groups, or the captured substrings will be part of the resulting array.

Comment: Actually, the `(?!(a-zA-Z0-9{8}))` regex pattern does not match any text, only locations (empty strings) that are not followed by `a` followed by `-`, followed by `z`.... and followed by 8 occurrences of the `9` digt.